# Finding 'x' in Excel

Tags: excel, function

I have a problem I need help with, please.

I want to find x in the following manner:

```
((a+x)/(b+x))>=c
```

This would be an extension to a simple calculation in my workplace, d=a/b where:

- *b* is the total number of incoming calls we receive
- *a* is the number of calls we could handle out of *b*, the total
- *d* shows our performance

So far so good. No function needed.

But we also have a **target**, *c*, in percentage - let's say 60% or 0.6
Ideally *a/b* should be bigger than *c*.

IF it is not, I'd like to know how many more incoming calls we need that are also handled (with *x* added to both *a* and *b* above) therefore slowly raising our performance over time.

*x* would show this extra number of handled calls, say, "5"

- I do not know what type of mathematics it is (I cannot recall it, shame on me)
- I do not know how to achieve it in Excel

Can someone please help? thank you!

Comment: try something on your own, we might help you then

Comment: Your goal should be `b*0.6` will tell you how many calls you need to handle to get more then 60% handled.

Comment: Philipp, thanks, that was really useful. As you can see below, there _are_ people who do help without an attitude.

user2140261, thanks but 'x' increases for both _a_ and _b_ so it was a bit more complex than that

Comment: @GaborBartal Philipp is referring to the [rules of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that request those asking questions to show their attempts. This helps those answering, so there isn't duplication in efforts or things you've already tried. It also helps those asking as they tend to learn more and further develop skills rather than just getting an answer and moving on, which is the main point of the site - learning and growth instead of pure question and answer. This is a different type of forum, hence the response.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I do agree with that and I do want to learn.
I have to admit I did not know the house rules in that detail. I however tried to describe it as best as I could, and came up with the formula.

His wording was misleading, "we might help you then" sounds dismissive, whereas "we might be able to help you then" makes it more obvious what he means.

Comment: @GaborBartal Passive wording vs Direct. Gets us Americans every time. :) Direct does not necessarily equal harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

((a+x)/(b+x))>=c

then

a+x >= c(b+x)

then

a+x >= cb+cx

then

a-cb >= cx-x

then

a-cb >= (c-1)x

then

(a-cb)/(c-1) >= x

So if you have values for a,b,c then the range for x is defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a nice breakdown - I'm rusty with maths already.
I've tried it as a formula and it works. Much appreciated!

Comment: You are quite welcome......I also am rusty with algebra (we just do not use it often).

Answer (score 1):

When you cannot solve the equation "analytically", you might use the "goal seek".

Use a param in any range, such as "A1". Fill it with any value looking like your answer (if you want a percentage put 50%, etc.).

```
A1=3
B1=((a+A1)/(b+A1))
```

Open "Data" tab and "What-If analysis" and "Goal Seek".

In "Set Cell", select "B1"
In "To Value", set the value you want to reach (0.6 in your sample)
In "By changing cell", set A1.

Click OK, see A1 becoming the expected result.

Comment: Wow this is a handy tool for brute force attempts, I already love this site :)
It took me like 15 mins of testing because it never found an answer then I realized I had to change everzthingto whole numbers, something like 50 and 90, so that if x is 10 than the numbers become 60 and 100 (clcearly giving 0.6).

Too bad one cannot automate it, so that if the numbers change (which they would as it's a live database) the Goal Seek keeps updating that field.

I really like this alternative solution - thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a case for a graphical presentation:

[image: SO21731509 example]

where the formula in F2 (copied down) is `=IF(E2>0,E2,0)` and a Stacked Column has been applied.

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks a lot for the effort! Especially with the little trick in F2 - that was just going to be the next thing I wanted to look up! Too bad I cannot upvote yet - when I get more points I will come back to give you the points too